# How to use the API key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out how to use [this API](http://docs.trnbattlefield.apiary.io/#), but I'm not sure what it means by needing to "populate the TRN-Api-Key header with your personal API key.". Where would I do this to get results from the API? If I just try putting the API URL with all the things filled out in my browser it doesn't give me a response since I need the API key, but I can't put it in the URL (at least it's not saying anything on how/where to put it). So I was just wondering how to put the API key in so it will let me see the results?

Here's the API I'm trying to use: http://docs.trnbattlefield.apiary.io/#

BTW, I'm trying to do this with HTML and Javascript / jQuery.

Comment: Look at the `headers` section in the jQuery ajax [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send the `TRN-Api-Key` header.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BF1 Tracker code examples on their site, and have many examples in different languages.  As you've asked regarding jQuery, I've copied the code directly from trnbattlefield and added the api-key.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://battlefieldtracker.com/bf1/api/Stats/BasicStats?
platform=3&personaId=xxxxxxxxxx&game=tunguska');

request.setRequestHeader('TRN-Api-Key', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

request.send();
```

Note, this is using the 'DetailedStats' api.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery's .ajax() instead of say .get(), which is just a thin wrapper around .ajax() anyway. .ajax() gives you an optional `headers` parameter where you can add custom headers, such as one with your personal API key. Headers are not part of the URL address itself.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/